# exim filter for unseen delivery to multiple addresses

Tags: email, redirect, exim, filter

I need to forward all mail to an address on to two other addresses, whilst keeping a copy of the original email. I've got the following exim filter set up:

```
unseen delivery address@anotherdomain.com, address@mydomain.com
```

but this give the following error message in the mainlog:

```
vhost_forward router: skipped error: missing or malformed local part (expected word or "<") in "unseen deliver address@anotherdomain.com"
```

what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Try doing two seperate lines; or surround each address with < >

Comment: separate lines **and** surrounding with <> worked! (if you put your comment as an answer i'll mark it as accepted answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing two seperate lines; or surround each address with < >.

(The full email address format as defined by RFC 822 allows the form "User Name ", and I think exim only allows one delivery per "delivery" line)

Comment: Yes [the manual](https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/filter_ch-exim_filter_files.html#SECTdeliver) states that:
**You can use more than one deliver command (each one may have only one address)** and that entries such as `"Dr Livingstone <David@somewhere.africa.example>"` are allowed.